# search the internet from your site via google?

Tags: api, search, embed

In the old days, I remember seeing websites with embedded google search boxes where you could choose whether you wanted to search the site or search the internet.
I'm trying to add a search box to my page that searches the internet, but using google custom search, it is only searching the local web site.

Is there another embeddable search box from google that I can use or a different configuration for the one I have that will make it search the web instead?
Thanks

```
<!-- Google Custom Search Element -->
<div id="cse" style="margin: 20px;width:85%;">Loading...</div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1');
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    var cse = new google.search.CustomSearchControl();
    cse.draw('cse');
    void(document.getElementsByName("search")[0].style.border="1px solid black");
  }, true);
</script>
</div>
```